# Filling a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have a few items in a Jpanel which is then pushed to the top and used as a toolbar for a basic search engine. I'm having an issue where my last combobox isn't displaying as there isn't enough room. However, there's a lot of empty space on the left side and I need everything to move across to fill the JPanel so then this can display. So my question is how would I make these items start from the far left and go to right, thanks.

```
    //Labels for combo boxes
    JLabel Bookmarklbl = new JLabel("Bookmarks:");
    JLabel Historylbl = new JLabel("History:");

    FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
    MainBrowser.toolBar.setLayout(flowLayout);

    //Adding items to Panel
    MainBrowser.toolBar.add(Bookmarklbl);
    MainBrowser.toolBar.add(BookmarkList);
    MainBrowser.toolBar.add(bookmarkbtn);
    MainBrowser.toolBar.add(back);
    MainBrowser.toolBar.add(forward);
    MainBrowser.toolBar.add(MainBrowser.addressbar);
    MainBrowser.toolBar.add(home);
    MainBrowser.toolBar.add(reload);
    MainBrowser.toolBar.add(Historylbl);
    MainBrowser.toolBar.add(historyList);

    //Set the things added from left to right
    MainBrowser.main.setComponentOrientation(
            ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

    //Add Panel to main frame 
    MainBrowser.main.add(MainBrowser.toolBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

How the bar looks:http://postimg.org/image/l314iw6eh/

Comment: what is toolbar here , is it JPanel??

Comment: @swapnil7 yep, its declared in a different class though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `toolbar` is `JPanel` and is using `FlowLayout`, this code might help you,

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // your toolbar panel
    FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) panel.getLayout(); // flowlayout
    flowLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT); // alignment to left
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH); // adding this panel to original frame
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yay! thank you this sets them all left but the history combobox still doesn't display but does when I remove another item. then showing the combobox bar is very large is there anyway I can limit the width?

Comment: well, you can use `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, y));`, but it is not recommended to hard code the size, as it will be displayed different on different resolutions. may be somebody can help us out here

Answer (score 1):

The default for a FlowLayout is CENTER. If there is not enough space to display all the components, then the components are wrapped to the next line. Changing the alignment to LEFT won't fix this problem (just the default alignment of components).

> showing the combobox bar is very large is there anyway I can limit the width?

You can limit the width of the combo box by using:

```
comboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue( "XXXXXXXXXX" );
```

This will limit the preferred size of the combo box so it can display on your toolbar.

However, you will still want to see the full text of the items when the popup is displayed. For this you can use the [Combo Box Popup](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/).

Comment: Thanks, this worked for setting the width I already awarded answer to first person but you helped a lot also!

Comment: @Corzuu, look at the `JTextField API`. There is a constructor that allows you to specify the number of columns for the text field. Also use proper variable names. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work.

`MainBrowser.toolbar.set(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));`

**EDIT**

Sorry it is `MainBrowser.toolbar.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));`

Comment: Getting the error "The method set(FlowLayout) is undefined for the type JPanel"

Comment: Sorry, it is `setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT))`, so use `MainBrowser.toolbar.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use BoxLayout, like:

```
toolBar.setLayout(new BoxLayout(toolBar,BoxLayout.X_AXIS)).
```